# Chr from VB6 translated to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, char, chr

I'm translating some hardware communication code from VB6 to C#, and got a problem with som communication that need to send chars to the device. The VB6 Code looks like this:

```
Dim STARTQUEST As String
STARTQUEST = Chr(254) + Chr(address + 8) + Chr(address) + Chr(20) + Chr(128) + Chr(3)
```

And I have done this C# code

```
String m_startQuest = "";
m_startQuest = m_startQuest + (Char)254 + (Char)(address + 8) + (Char)address + (Char)20 + (Char)128 + (Char)3;
```

But I get the feel that I don't get the same output from them. Atleast in debug the `STARTQUEST` string looks alot different. Is there any other way to get the vb6 function to do the same in C#?

Comment: from the char codes it looks like you should be using `byte[]` instead of strings.

Comment: Is there difference between C# and VB6 that is the reason to use  `byte[]` instead? Since the VB6 code I know is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and use the Strings.Chr function

[Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is doing a lot more behind the scenes than you may realize (see the link).

Comment: This I like alot. Didn't know this was a possibility!

Comment: Corrected post. Should be Strings.Chr not String.Chr.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
m_startQuest += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
  new byte[] {254, address + 8, address, 28, 128, 3}
);
```

Why bytes? .Net `char` type supports Unicode and may be bigger than 255. SO it is safer to use bytes.

Update:

A **runtime** error in VB6

```vb
Dim s As String
s = Chr(1) + Chr(256)
Debug.Print s
```

Result is 257 in c#.

```cs
(((char)1) + ((char)256))
```

Result is a string in c#.

```cs
(((char)1) + "" + ((char)256))
```

a **compile** time error in c#.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
  new byte[] { 1, 256 }
);
```

Comment: Ok, this gets me the same result as my original code, but I like the part that is safter! Is there a possibility that it's just some "showing error" that makes the vb6 string look different from the C# string?

Answer (score 0):

Using the (Char) cast gets you the behaviour of VB6's ChrW (not Chr) function. VB6's Chr function does an ANSI<->Unicode conversion - to duplicate this in C# you can use System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes().